# How to authentication API controller

Tags: api, authentication, grails

I'm wondering if there's anyone who can explain to me how I have to construct my Authentication API controller.

- I have a native IOS application
- I have a grails backend service

For the moment I'm using fixed user credentials(for development) in my IOS application (I know these credentials exists). Now I want to make this flexible by providing a login controller.

In my backend, I'm using spring security with basic authentication. So when I make a connection to my backend, I provide a username and password in the http header.

My real question here is what I should provide in a Authentication API controller. I want to use this controller to check if the user exists, and the password is correct.

Anyone who has experience with this?

Can't I just use an empty authentication controller with the spring-security method @Secured(['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'])

If I'm correct it'll send back the proper http status codes isn't it?

Comment: You have not mentioned about using the Spring Security Core Plugin in Grails? Are you? `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` authenticates anonymous and remember-me user, which should be good, but if you need role based authorization then you have to do some more. Refer [this](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/5%20Configuring%20Request%20Mappings%20to%20Secure%20URLs.html) for details.